# how to disable radio button in angular 5 app

Tags: angular, typescript, radio-button

I need to disable radio button by another external checkbox click event which is generated dynamically using reactive form/ formGroup.

my component code works for textbox and dropdown but not for radio or checkbox

### this is generated code

```
    <label _ngcontent-c6="" class="container-vertical"> Dog
    <input _ngcontent-c6="" type="radio" ng-reflect-form-control-name="01cb437e-0015-4c45-9828-fb2d1d" ng-reflect-value="8f77b6e1-2495-4781-9e40-520e94" ng-reflect-name="01cb437e-0015-4c45-9828-fb2d1d" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid"> 


    <label _ngcontent-c6="" class="container-vertical"> Cat
    <input _ngcontent-c6="" type="radio" ng-reflect-form-control-name="01cb437e-0015-4c45-9828-fb2d1d" ng-reflect-value="4102b66c-b8c3-4d41-afcd-5852e4" ng-reflect-name="01cb437e-0015-4c45-9828-fb2d1d" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid"> 

    <label _ngcontent-c6="" class="container-vertical"> Fish
    <input _ngcontent-c6="" type="radio" ng-reflect-form-control-name="01cb437e-0015-4c45-9828-fb2d1d" ng-reflect-value="5dc08818-38b0-4563-8e0a-ce8901" ng-reflect-name="01cb437e-0015-4c45-9828-fb2d1d" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid">
```

### template

```
<div *ngSwitchCase="'radio'">
           <div *ngFor="let opt of question.options" > <small>radio</small>
               <label class="container-vertical"> {{opt.value}}
                       <input type="radio" 
                              [formControlName]="question.key"  
                              [value]="opt.key" 
                              [(ngModel)]="question.value"
                              (change)="onChangeValue(question.value, previousValue, responseId, question.key, 'radio'); previousValue = question.value" 
                              (focus)="previousValue=question.value"
                              > 


                       <span class="checkmark"></span>
               </label>
           </div> 
       </div>
```

### component

```
  private handleQuestionAnswerProvidedStateChange(questionAnswerProvidedState:QuestionAnswerProvidedStateDataModel)
 {

   var formControlNameReference = questionAnswerProvidedState.QuestionId.substring(1,30);
//  ???????????? need help here ... how to get reference of radio button to disable it

  if(questionAnswerProvidedState!=null)
  {
    var elementReference = <HTMLInputElement> document.getElementById(questionAnswerProvidedState.QuestionId);
    if(questionAnswerProvidedState.AnswerNotProvided == true)
    {
      elementReference.disabled = true;
      elementReference.value = "";
      elementReference.classList.add("disableInput");
    }
    else if(questionAnswerProvidedState.AnswerNotProvided == false)
    {
      elementReference.disabled = false;
      elementReference.classList.remove("disableInput");
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Comment: This hurts my eyes a bit... this is so not how you code Angular ;) Don't access the dom like that...

Comment: you can simply use `[disabled]` property binding with the required condition.

Comment: i need to bind disable with another checkbox checked, which is working for textbox for me at the movement

Answer (score 2):

```html
<input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="radioButtonVisibility" [attr.disabled]="flag ? '' : null" 
       formControlName="radioButtonVisibility"/>
```

Use the above attribute `[attr.disabled]`. If the variable flag contains any value then the radio button will be disabled. If the variable flag is `null` then the radio button will be enabled. The flag value has to be set to null or not null as per the requirement.

Comment: It works for input radio, but not for ng-select